# Fail to change CS register value from kernel mode. invalid opcode: 0000

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel, x86-64, inline-assembly, att

From module code with this snippet I'm trying to change the value of CS register:

```
asm("pushq %rax");
asm("mov $0x10,%rax");
asm("mov %rax,%cs");
asm("popq %rax");
```

Actually the CS register contains segment selector - `$0x10`, also this value returned by kernel macro `__KERNEL_CS`. And what I want to do that is rewrite CS register with exactly the same value. Unfortunately I get error, without the snippet the error is absent.

```
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.693297] invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] SMP 
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.694223] CPU: 0 PID: 7140 Comm: insmod Tainted: P           OE   4.4.0-148-generic #174~14.04.1-Ubuntu
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.694362] task: ffff88007a0edb00 ti: ffff880068c54000 task.ti: ffff880068c54000
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.694420] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffc114e114>]  [<ffffffffc114e114>] hello_init+0x44/0xe0 [hello_module]
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.694497] RSP: 0018:ffff880068c57ca0  EFLAGS: 00010282
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.694540] RAX: 0000000000000010 RBX: ffffffff81e15080 RCX: 0000000000005768
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.694595] RDX: 000000000000b1e4 RSI: 0000000000000246 RDI: 0000000000000246
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.694649] RBP: ffff880068c57cc0 R08: 3231203a657a6973 R09: 6461202c66373a37
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.694703] R10: 203a737365726464 R11: 0000000000000363 R12: ffff8800b7e7e980
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.694757] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffffffffc114e0d0 R15: ffff880068c57eb0
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.694813] FS:  00007f8c1c36b740(0000) GS:ffff88013fa00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.694875] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.694920] CR2: 00005575a6b20248 CR3: 0000000075efc000 CR4: 0000000000060670
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.694975] Stack:
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.694995]  0000000000000000 007f000081e15080 ffff88013fa0c000 ffffffff81e15080
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.695065]  ffff880068c57d38 ffffffff8100216f ffff880068c57eb0 ffff880068c57d10
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.695133]  0000000000000246 0000000000000002 ffffffff811eab7f ffff88013b003c00
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.695201] Call Trace:
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.695230]  [<ffffffff8100216f>] do_one_initcall+0xcf/0x200
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.695281]  [<ffffffff811eab7f>] ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x1af/0x220
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.695338]  [<ffffffff8118d293>] ? do_init_module+0x27/0x1d2
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.695387]  [<ffffffff8118d2cc>] do_init_module+0x60/0x1d2
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.695432]  [<ffffffff8110b42d>] load_module+0x145d/0x1b50
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.695480]  [<ffffffff81107b60>] ? __symbol_put+0x40/0x40
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.695528]  [<ffffffff812137a1>] ? kernel_read+0x41/0x60
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.695574]  [<ffffffff8110bcee>] SYSC_finit_module+0x7e/0xa0
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.695620]  [<ffffffff8110bd2e>] SyS_finit_module+0xe/0x10
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.697884]  [<ffffffff8182d61b>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x22/0xcb
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.700094] Code: eb 03 c0 0f 01 45 ee 0f b7 75 ee 48 8b 4d f0 48 c7 c7 9d f0 14 c1 31 c0 89 f2 e8 73 eb 03 c0 8c 5d ec 41 55 49 c7 c5 10 00 00 00 <49> 8e cd 41 5d 8c 4d ea 0f b7 55 ec 0f b7 75 ea 48 c7 c7 b8 f0 
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.704976] RIP  [<ffffffffc114e114>] hello_init+0x44/0xe0 [hello_module]
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.707358]  RSP <ffff880068c57ca0>
Aug  1 20:26:37 myhost kernel: [ 2905.719667] ---[ end trace 48f04fe6e7ff0ed6 ]---
```

**Updated with `R13` register**

```
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.818158] invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] SMP 
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.818699] CPU: 1 PID: 5108 Comm: insmod Tainted: P           OE   4.4.0-148-generic #174~14.04.1-Ubuntu
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.818778] task: ffff880097a45b00 ti: ffff880085d58000 task.ti: ffff880085d58000
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.818810] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffc109e114>]  [<ffffffffc109e114>] hello_init+0x44/0xe0 [hello_module]
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.818854] RSP: 0018:ffff880085d5bca0  EFLAGS: 00010282
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.818880] RAX: 000000000000001f RBX: ffffffff81e15080 RCX: 0000000000002298
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.818911] RDX: 00000000000051a2 RSI: 0000000000000246 RDI: 0000000000000246
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.818942] RBP: ffff880085d5bcc0 R08: 3231203a657a6973 R09: 6461202c66373a37
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.818973] R10: 203a737365726464 R11: 0000000000000353 R12: ffff880085cc0b60
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.819004] R13: 0000000000000010 R14: ffffffffc109e0d0 R15: ffff880085d5beb0
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.819037] FS:  00007fd564d44740(0000) GS:ffff88013fa40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.819072] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.819097] CR2: 0000558a2aa16248 CR3: 0000000085d5c000 CR4: 0000000000060670
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.819128] Stack:
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.819139]  0000000000000000 007f000081e15080 ffff88013fa4c000 ffffffff81e15080
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.819178]  ffff880085d5bd38 ffffffff8100216f ffff880085d5beb0 ffff880085d5bd10
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.819217]  0000000000000246 0000000000000002 ffffffff811eab7f ffff88013b003c00
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.819255] Call Trace:
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.819273]  [<ffffffff8100216f>] do_one_initcall+0xcf/0x200
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.819301]  [<ffffffff811eab7f>] ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x1af/0x220
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.819332]  [<ffffffff8118d293>] ? do_init_module+0x27/0x1d2
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.819359]  [<ffffffff8118d2cc>] do_init_module+0x60/0x1d2
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.819385]  [<ffffffff8110b42d>] load_module+0x145d/0x1b50
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.819412]  [<ffffffff81107b60>] ? __symbol_put+0x40/0x40
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.819440]  [<ffffffff812137a1>] ? kernel_read+0x41/0x60
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.819466]  [<ffffffff8110bcee>] SYSC_finit_module+0x7e/0xa0
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.819492]  [<ffffffff8110bd2e>] SyS_finit_module+0xe/0x10
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.820820]  [<ffffffff8182d61b>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x22/0xcb
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.822117] Code: eb 0e c0 0f 01 45 ee 0f b7 75 ee 48 8b 4d f0 48 c7 c7 9d f0 09 c1 31 c0 89 f2 e8 73 eb 0e c0 8c 5d ec 41 55 49 c7 c5 10 00 00 00 <49> 8e cd 41 5d 8c 4d ea 0f b7 55 ec 0f b7 75 ea 48 c7 c7 b8 f0 
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.824981] RIP  [<ffffffffc109e114>] hello_init+0x44/0xe0 [hello_module]
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.826376]  RSP <ffff880085d5bca0>
Aug  1 21:05:25 myhost kernel: [  146.833469] ---[ end trace 6525f2f63d2f58dd ]---
```

Comment: This may seem like an odd question but were you using another register like R13 rather than RAX at some poiint?

Comment: Yes, I also used RBX and R13. Output the same.

Comment: few minutes. and i will post

Comment: Done. Here it is. You can see `R13: 0000000000000010`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't mov set CS, the code segment register, even though it can set others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52490438/why-cant-mov-set-cs-the-code-segment-register-even-though-it-can-set-others)

Comment: Just curious; why do you want to do this?  I don't think reloading CS with the same value can't have any architectural effect.  Unless you're worried that CS might *not* have been set to `__KERNEL_CS` before this?

Comment: @PeterCordes : I'd love to know that as well. There is a possibility there could be an XY problem here.

Comment: There is no any special. I learn kernel. Try different actions and observe. If everything ok - I go proper way. Before same value I tried another, but it didn't work as well. I simplified case to the same value. Thank you for interest :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `mov` instruction to write to `cs`. From [Intel® 64 and IA-32 architectures software developer’s manual](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm), [MOV spec](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/39/c5/325462-sdm-vol-1-2abcd-3abcd.pdf#page=1208):

> The MOV instruction cannot be used to load the CS register. Attempting to do so results in an invalid opcode exception (#UD).

You need to do a far jump to change `cs`, check restrictions in [ch.5.8](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/39/c5/325462-sdm-vol-1-2abcd-3abcd.pdf#page=2862) for changing `cs`.

Answer (score 7):

You can't load *CS* directly with a selector with [`MOV`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov). You will need to use a [`RETFQ`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ret) or [`IRETQ`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/iret:iretd) instruction to change *CS* and go to a 64-bit offset. From the instruction set reference:

> The MOV instruction cannot be used to load the CS register. Attempting to do so results in an invalid opcode exception (#UD). To load the CS register, use the far JMP, CALL, or RET instruction.

You are getting #UD (invalid opcode) and that is why your module crashes.

In 64-bit code there is no [FAR CALL](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call) or [FAR JMP](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jmp) that takes a selector and a 64-bit offset as operands (immediate values) as there is no `ptr16:64` variant.

[image]

In 32-bit mode you could have done an `ljmpl $0x10, $offset` but in 64-bit code you have to use an alternative<sup>1</sup> like *RETFQ* (or an *IRETQ* if you need a privilege level change). You could use code like this:

```
asm ("push %[sel]\n\t"
     "push $1f\n\t"
     "retfq\n\t"
     "1:"
     :
     : [sel]"i"(__KERNEL_CS));
```

If you want to use basic inline assembly as in your question you need to place consecutive `ASM` statements into one statement. The compiler is allowed to generate code between your individual `ASM` statements which isn't what you'd want. A basic `ASM` version would be:

```
asm ("push $0x10\n\t"
     "push $1f\n\t"
     "retfq\n\t"
     "1:");
```

It is important to note that you need to override `RETF` to be of `Q`uadword size as the default `RETF` in 64-bit code assumes a 32-bit return address and we want to specify that we want to return to a 64-bit address. From the Intel documentation for [`RET`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ret):

> **In 64-bit mode**, the default operation size of this instruction is the stack-address size, i.e. 64 bits. This applies to near returns, not far returns; **the default operation size of far returns is 32 bits**.

This code simulates a FAR JMP to the next instruction by pushing the selector on the stack<sup>2</sup> followed by the offset (label `1:`) of the instruction after the `retfq`. `retfq` will pop off the offset and selector and transfer control to that address which happens to be the next instruction.

---

### Footnotes:

- <sup>1</sup>It is possible to create a variable that is 10 bytes in length which includes a QWORD for the offset to jump to and a WORD for the selector. You can then use the `JMP m16:64` jump variant. To encode a `JMP m16:m64` in GCC's inline assembly using AT&T syntax you could do this:

  ```
  asm ("push %[sel]\n\t"
       "push $1f\n\t"
       "rex.W ljmp *(%%rsp)\n\t"
       "1:add $16, %%rsp\n\t"
       :
       : [sel]"i"(__KERNEL_CS));
  ```

  The code builds a `16:64` (selector:offset) pointer on the stack and does an indirect FAR JMP through *RSP* to it. The `16:64` address points to the instruction after the FAR JMP. The `rex.W` prefix promotes the FAR JMP so that the pointer is decoded with a 64-bit offset rather than a 32-bit offset. The stack is then cleaned up removing the pointer from the stack.

  I don't know the context or the reason you are changing *CS*, but if it is a frequent occurrence that the code is called then you may wish to emit the `16:64` pointer in the code itself. In the following example the `16:64` pointer is stored after the FAR JMP instruction, and the instruction to jump to is at label `2:` (**after** the `16:64` pointer):

  ```
  asm ("rex.W ljmp *1f\n\t"
       /* The pointer is being stored with the code.
          The jump will be to the label after the pointer itself at label '2:'. */
       "1:  .quad 2f\n\t"
       "    .word %c[sel]\n\t"
       "2:\n\t"
       :
       : [sel]"i"(__KERNEL_CS));
  ```
- <sup>2</sup>The Linux kernel itself doesn't have a [Red Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_zone_(computing)) so it is safe to push information on the stack directly with inline assembly. In user mode code you would have to adjust *RSP* to avoid clobbering the 128 bytes directly below *RSP*.

Comment: Should this be using `asm goto` somehow to let the compiler know that execution won't resume?  Or at least a `"memory"` clobber to make sure the compiler doesn't reorder an assignment after the `asm` (which would mean the store never happens if execution doesn't return.)

Comment: @PeterCordes : I don't believe so because the label being used as a jump target is always inside the inline assembly. In all cases the code in inline assembly actually continues. The only thing that is happening is that CS is being reloaded. Execution is always returning. I don't see where you are looking at a case where it doesn't return? The FAR JMP is always to a label inside the inline assembly. In 64-bit code the limit and base on CS are always ignored so the FAR JMP will always be to same linear address. Diff story in 32-bit code though where you can change CS and it may go elsewhere.

Comment: @PeterCordes : But one question I have for the OP is why he is reloading _CS_ this way at all unless there was a privilege level change.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Oh, I missed that it was just a reload with the same value, not an actual jump to a 32-bit code segment or something.  I don't see why that would ever be useful except maybe for microarchitectural reasons like a delay or instruction-reordering barrier like `lfence`.  For other cases where you're actually *changing* `cs`, at least a `"memory"` clobber would be a good idea.